# Refresh table but don't hide div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page that displays information in a table like a train or airport arrivals board. I have an edit button beside each entry which pops up a div to edit the data.

Problem is I have the table refreshing every 20 seconds and the popup div disappears.

Popup show:

```
function loadFlight() {
    document.getElementById("myDialog").innerHTML='<input type="button" onclick="$(\'#myDialog\').hide()" value="Close"></input><object type="text/html" id="edit"  width="800px" height="430px" data="edit_train.php" ></object>';
    $('#myDialog').height('500px');
    $('#myDialog').width('900px');
    $('#myDialog').show();
}
```

HTML on the current page:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            refreshTable();
        });
        function refreshTable(){
            $('#tableHolder').load('traininfo.php', function(){                    
                setTimeout(refreshTable, (10*1000));
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div id="tableHolder">
        <p>Loading</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

The page that loads contains:

```
<div class="content">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dublin</td>
            <td>Cork</td>
        <tr>
</div>
```

I have also tried it with ajax using the tutorial from [W3 Schools - Ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)
But it still hides on refresh.

Any idea how I can reload the page without closing the div ?

Comment: Not enough information given. Is this div inside the table? Provide html structure

Comment: Can you post your `HTML` code?

Comment: disable the refresh if the edit button gets clicked? And note that w3fools is a total crap resource.

Comment: @MarcB never thought about doing that. Ill do that now, Thanks